# input value returns empty at first and repeating letter

Tags: javascript

I have an `input` that I want to track it with each keydown event but at the first time I'm getting empty output and then one of letters repeating itself.
try `sssd` for input , first you will get empty output and at last you will get ssss
and I tried on other events too

```js
let theinput = document.getElementById("clrinput");

theinput.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  console.log(theinput.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clrinput">
```

Comment: The `keydown` event occurs before the value is updated.

Comment: the inputs value doesn't change on keydown - ahh, the bold statement that "this is not a similar question" has been removed - I found a repeat

Comment: @Barmar I tried any other events

Comment: @Bravo I tried any other events too

Comment: @IhateReact what about using `keyup` or `keypress`?

Comment: You only get the letter repeating itself if you hold down the key, because of auto-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `input` event.. ?

```js
let theinput = document.getElementById('clrinput');

theinput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  console.clear()
  console.log( theinput.value )
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clrinput">
```

Comment: Yup. This is working too. Actually keyup was working too but my liveserver had problem

Comment: @IhateReact  `keyup` does not work on a mouse event, like a right click to execute a text past

Answer (score 1):

As  Barmar pointed out the `keydown` happens before the value is updated, if you change to `keyup` it works fine

```js
let theinput = document.getElementById("clrinput");

theinput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  console.log(theinput.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clrinput">
```